# nltk error when trying to write tokenization output to file

Tags: python, nltk, fwrite

I have a large text file (~300MB) that I want to tokenize into individual sentences. The code I'm using is the following:

```
import nltk.data
f = open(filename)
r = read()
s = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')
print('\n---\n'.join(s.tokenize(r.strip())))
```

This works fine, but it just prints it to stdout. I want to save the result in a separate file to do other stuff with it, and this is when I'm failing. If I write

```
file = open('saetze.txt', 'w')
print('\n---\n'.join(s.tokenize(r.strip()))).file.write()
```

I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'`, and if I write

```
file = open('saetze.txt', 'w')
print('\n---\n'.join(s.tokenize(r.strip()))).file.write() >> file
```

Then I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'str' and 'file'`

So, what is the correct syntax to write the output to file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use the word "file" as it is a python keyword. Use some other word say "fp" as file pointer of the file to be written. Now to write into the file use the below statement:

```
fp.write('\n---\n'.join(s.tokenize(r.strip())))
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it clearer, the OP is asking for a sentence tokenizer and how to use the sentence tokenizer in NLTK such that it outputs to a file:

```
$ echo "Frau Präsidentin! Ist meine Stimme mitgezählt worden? Betrachten wir z.B. die Automobilindustrie, wo die Subventionen und verschiedenen staatlichen Beihilfen während des Berichtszeitraums um 24% gestiegen sind. Zu welchem Zweck?" > in.txt
$ cat in.txt
Frau Präsidentin! Ist meine Stimme mitgezählt worden? Betrachten wir z.B. die Automobilindustrie, wo die Subventionen und verschiedenen staatlichen Beihilfen während des Berichtszeitraums um 24% gestiegen sind. Zu welchem Zweck?

$ python
>>> import io
>>> import nltk
>>> sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle')
>>> with io.open('in.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin, io.open('out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fout:
...     sentences = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(fin.read())
...     fout.write('\n'.join(sentences))
>>> exit()

$ cat out.txt
Frau Präsidentin!
Ist meine Stimme mitgezählt worden?
Betrachten wir z.B. die Automobilindustrie, wo die Subventionen und verschiedenen staatlichen Beihilfen während des Berichtszeitraums um 24% gestiegen sind.
Zu welchem Zweck?
```